# Combine multiple products into one (AngularJs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, structure, project

we have currently one product/project and now want to build another one. This should kind of integrate into the existing one, therefore are several ideas in the room.

A) Build kind of a Main-Project which is kind of a frame in which other parts of the two products will be loaded.

*Open Questions:*

- LazyLoading is possible but is it a good solution? (https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs)
- Can all things of components/directives/services be loaded from another product?

B) Each product runs own it owns and just load shared components (like a navbar, which should look like the same) or so and uses SingleSignOn to switch between products easily. Switching would look like Google-Apps is doing that.

*Open Questions:*

- How can a SingleSignOn easily be achived with multiple Angular-Products/Projects?

Which way would you prefer? And why?

Best regards and thanks a lot!

Comment: This is not really a coding question now is it ?

Comment: I think it depends on the question what coding is, coding contains also structure of coding and coding concepts. So in my eyes it's a coding question.

Comment: I can see no effort of work, you don't seem to have done any research yourself, there is no "one answer fits all" for this, so it's not a coding question. Anyway more suited to theory : http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

SingleSignOn is a matter of server, not front if the product are on the same front web application then you just sign once on the server.

For complex web application design you might want use ui-router instead of the classic ng-route. It replace the route concepts by state, with the possibility t nested them easily.

Since you have multiple products you probably have some elements in common like user, authentication, etc.

In order to have this is common and be able to share it with the products just create a separate module 'common' and make the module of your product depends on 'common' and everything defined in 'common' will be available.